# When I pay for a Twilio account, can I send SMS FROM any number?

Tags: twilio

I am searching for a service that will allow my website users to send sms messages FROM their own cell numbers, but using my website. Is that possible with Twilio? It appears as though the from address always must be the twilio phone number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While caller ID spoofing for phone calls is frowned upon, but generally permissible, federal law in many countries prohibits the spoofing of sender information on SMS messages. As a result, Twilio will only send messages from numbers purchased through Twilio, or in some circumstances, your own personal phone number that you've verified with Twilio (this is mostly just for voice calls, though).

According to [the Twilio documentation for the REST API](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-required), only Twilio phone numbers are allowed as the "From" parameter:

> A Twilio phone number enabled for the type of message you wish to
>   send. Only phone numbers or short codes purchased from Twilio work
>   here; you cannot (for example) spoof messages from your own cell phone
>   number.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about that and realized that although my intents are honorable, it would be possible for me to run up someone else's phone bill by sending erroneous 'texts' from them. I ended up going with plovio as they had far better and accessible tech support. I was up and running in less than 15 minutes.

Comment: What are the "certain circumstances"? I have a need to send SMS messages as if they came from my own cell phone.